# Перевод азбуки морзе в русские буквы

Tags: python, python-3.x, перевод

Имеется код для перевода кода морзе в буквы, однако он не хочет переводить больше двух букв. Как можно переделать код, что бы все буквы, разделенные пробелами, переводились в текст?

```
message = input("Please type a message to encrypt: ")
new_message = ""

letters = {".-": "A",
           "-...": "B",
           "-.-.": "C",}

if letters[message]:
    new_message = letters[message]
else:
    new_message = "This cannot be turned to morse code"
print(new_message)
```

Comment: У вас какая-то путаница. Вы текст в морзе переводите или наоборот? Таблица то для перевода морзе в текст, а надписи на английском говорят обратное.

Answer (score 1):

```
message = input("Please type a message to encrypt: ")
letters = {"A": ".-",
           "B": "-...",
           "C": "-.-.",
           ...
}

new_message = ""
for ch in message:
    try:
        new_message += letters.get(ch)
    except:
        print('This symbol cannot be turned to morse code')
        exit(0)

print(new_message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
message = input("Please type a message to encrypt: ")
new_message = ""

letters = {".-": "A",
           "-...": "B",
           "-.-.": "C",}

for char in message.split():
    if char in letters:
        new_message += letters[char]
    else:
        new_message = "This cannot be turned to morse code"
        break
print(new_message)
```

Только надписи на английском при этом у вас говорят, что вы наоборот переводите текст в код морзе.