# Азбука Морзе на Python

Tags: python

Затрудняюсь написать код перевода списка

```
m = ['А Б В В']
```

в список вида

```
m = ['.-  -...  .--  .--']
```

без использования встроенных функций.

Написал для этого свою пробную функцию:

```
def morze(symbol):
    
    if symbol == 'A':
        return '.-'
    
    if symbol == 'Б':
        return '-...'
        
    if symbol == 'В':
        return '.--'
    
    if symbol == ' ':
        return '  '
        
    else: return 0
```

И пробую вывести так:

```
for i in range(0,len(m)):

    print(morze(m[i]), end = " ")
```

Но конечно же ничего не работает. Есть [рекомандация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1031421/%D0%90%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80-%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F). Однако, она с синтаксисом Java, который мне абсолютно не знаком. Есть так же предложение [такого вида](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1171008/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B). Но там используется функция get, что противоречит заданию.

Список вида

```
m = ['А', 'Б', 'В', 'В']
```

перевожу без проблем. Но нужно именно m = ['А Б В В'], где символы разделены не кавычками а пробелами.

Возможно ли это сделать?

Как синтаксически правильно реализовать посимвольный перевод на Python без использования вспомогательных функций?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку у вас список из одного элемента, вам нужно итерироваться по этому первому элементу `m[0]`:

```
for i in range(0,len(m[0])):
    print(morze(m[0][i]), end = " ")
```

Так почти всё работает за исключением того, что у вас в списке буква `А` русская, а в коде программы, где вы проверяете `if symbol == 'A':` у вас буква `A` латинская, поэтому это сравнение не срабатывает. Буква должна быть одинаковая и тогда всё заработает.

Comment: Спасибо. Это как раз то, что было нужно.

Answer (score 1):

вы можете попробовать сделать каждого члена списка ['А Б В В'] отдельным элементом: ['А', 'Б', 'В', 'В']
Затем вы можете работать с новым списком

```
m = ['А Б В В']
m = m[0].split()
print(m)
```

Comment: Без функции split() не получится сделать? А если и получится, то результат будет повторять исходный код самой функции split()?

Comment: Да, мы можем написать по-другому, но код, который мы должны использовать для этого, будет длинным.
в некоторых случаях, которые мы можем использовать для решения проблемы, да, они будут повторять действие split ()

Answer (score 0):

У Вас в изначальном списке m находится лишь 1 элемент - это строка 'А Б В В', соответственно на выходе будет 0.
Либо сделайте правильный список, либо работайте со строкой.
З.Ы. Следите за раскладкой ;-)

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Оформите свой "ответ" как комментарий к вопросу, а этот "ответ" удалите.